# How do I shift a Core-Plot X Label to between ticks?

Tags: core-plot

How do I shift an X-axis label's text to the right (horizontal)?
I want to be able to display a string between two x-ticks (e.g., | Jan | Feb |...) versus by default, straddling the x-tick.

I tried the following:

```
newLabel = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc] initWithText:item.month textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
newLabel.tickLocation = [[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:index] decimalValue];

CGPoint myPoint = newLabel.contentLayer.position;
CGFloat x = myPoint.x;
CGPoint yourPoint = myPoint;
yourPoint.x += 16.0;

[newLabel positionBetweenViewPoint:myPoint andViewPoint:yourPoint forCoordinate:CPTCoordinateX inDirection:CPTSignPositive];
```

...but I got an SIGABRT error (crash).
An example is worth a thousand words.

Regards,
   Ric

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to do that right now. You'll need to use custom labels. Set the axis labeling policy to `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone` and set up the tick locations and labels that you want. See the [labeling policy demo](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/examples/CorePlotGallery/src/plots/LabelingPolicyDemo.m#75) in the Plot Gallery app for some sample code.